# what is the meaning of "canvas is pixel based" and SVG is vector based

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

I have gone through canvas and SVG in html5. When it comes to the difference, It is mentioned that canvas is pixel based and SVG is vector based. I have not got what do they mean by these.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics

Comment: can you give me an example, I am not clear

Comment: Have you read the articles?

Comment: yes, i got a top level idea. If the resolution is increased, Canvas loses its quality and vector does not. Right?

Comment: More or less, yes. If you scale bitmap (canvas) up, the image becomes pixelated. If you scale it down, you lose details. Vector images remain perfect in every case.

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Vector images can not be scaled perfectly they are limited by the precision of the device that renders them. This means there is a limit to the detail that they can hold. As with all digital data they to have aliasing artifacts.

Comment: @Blindman67: well, that's a limitation of the device, not the image format, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev min requirement for SVG is single 32bit float, with views to do calculations as doubles (64bit). Thought higher precision is possible the min spec are the limits you need to consider when creating content. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#Precision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 way to register an image in your computer:

- **Register in pixel**: It means that your image is register as a table of pixel. And in every box of your table a color is register. Such images, have a defined size (1 computer pixel for 1 table box). If you want to reduce the size, an algorithm will mix pixel to render a lower size image. And if you want to display bigger than it is you will see pixel or the image will become blurred.
- **Register in vector**: This kind of image do not own a size. Indeed the file format register vector (direction and scale). And when you want to display it, you will specify a size and the computer will process your image to display it. If you zoom on the image (for example a line). You will never see pixels. Indeed every time you zoom, the image is reprocessed and a line stay a line.